# Obtener directorio de proyecto desde cualquier PC

Tags: java, archivo

Deseo abrir un archivo txt contenido en mi proyecto desde cualquier PC.

Tengo un problema a la hora de abrir un archivo txt que esta en la carpeta recursos de mi proyecto. La cuestión es que puedo abrir el archivo si especifico la ruta del mismo a partir de mi disco duro, pero no va a funcionar si el proyecto es ejecutado en otra computadora.

Así es como lo abro:

```
String directorio =
"D:\\EscritorioWindows\\Proyecto\\src\\recursos\\records.txt";
records = new File(directorio);
```

> Entonces, me gustaría saber como abrir un recurso desde mi proyecto
>   desde cualquier PC.

Cualquier sugerencia es agradecida. Saludos!

Comment: En realidad puedes realizarlo : String directorio = new File (".").getAbsolutePath() + "\\src\\recursos\\records.txt" o new File ("src/recursos/records.txt").getAbsolutePath();, también  anexo en mi respuesta otra forma de obtener el directorio de tu proyecto usando System.getProperty("user.dir")

Answer (score 1):

Intenta cambiando el path por algo así: "\Proyecto\src\recursos\records.txt"

Comment: por favor revisa [answer] y explica mejor tu respuesta pues parece simplemente un comentario, añade las razones de pór que esto soluciona el problema

Comment: Pude solucionar el problema. Solo indico las carpetas dentro del proyecto y despues obtengo la direccion absoluta.

    String direccion = new 
    File("src/recursos/records.txt").getAbsolutePath();
    System.out.println(direccion);
    records = new File(direccion);

Comment: Gracias por tu sugerencia. :)

Answer (score 1):

Para obtener la ruta del directorio de tu proyecto en cualquier pc puedes realizarlo usando alguna de estas opciones.

---

**1)** Usando `System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\"`

Si la ruta que deseas obtener es

```
D:\\EscritorioWindows\\Proyecto\\src\\recursos\\records.txt
```

se obtendría de esta forma:

```
String directorio = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\recursos\\records.txt"
```

---

**2)** Usando `new File (".").getAbsolutePath()`

Si la ruta que deseas obtener es

```
D:\\EscritorioWindows\\Proyecto\\src\\recursos\\records.txt
```

Se obtendría de esta forma:

```
String directorio = new File (".").getAbsolutePath() + "\\src\\recursos\\records.txt"
```

**3)** o usando una varian de la anterior, usando `new File ("<Ruta de archivo dentro de tu proyecto>").getAbsolutePath()`

Si la ruta que deseas obtener es

```
D:\\EscritorioWindows\\Proyecto\\src\\recursos\\records.txt
```

Se obtendría de esta forma:

```
String directorio = new File ("src/recursos/records.txt").getAbsolutePath();
```